# Hiding a Section on Dynamics 365 using JS

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm

I'm trying to take a field value (that's a two option check box) and if it is checked then set the visibility on a section to be true, and if it's not checked then to set the visibility to false. I have it set on the field to call the function on an on change event.

When I go into the form and either check the box or uncheck the box it gives me a script error.

This is the function I'm using:

```
function SetProductVisible(){


    if (Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ee_productspecific").getValue()){
         Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(“SubGrids”).sections.get(“Products”).setVisible(true);  
    }

    else{
        Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get(“SubGrids”).sections.get(“Products”).setVisible(false);      
   }
};
```

Thank you for your help.

The fields default value is also set to "No"

Comment: Open dev tools in your browser and then perform the action that generates the error.  The debugger in script tools should automatically break at the exception.  I know that is the behavior with Chrome and FF's dev tools, with IE's you might have to tick an option to pause on exceptions.

Comment: You most probably do not have the correct tab or section names, start by checking the tab/section names on the form (customization).

Answer (score 2):

Ensure that you are using the right quotation marks by replacing `“` and `”` with `"`.

As mentioned in the comments, also ensure that you are using the right name for your tab and section, and check the developer console for more information about the error.

Comment: It's most likely this. The "'s around 'SubGrids' and 'Products' in the code will need to be manually replaced. This usually happens when copying and pasting code from a browser

Answer (score 1):

here is your solution...

I created a new field on the CRM form called "log_showhide" which is a two option field. You need to edit the code below to match your Section name and field name with the correct values...

Furthermore, I would set the code to run on load of the form as well as on change of your field.

This method is applicable to Microsoft Dynamics 365 v9.x

```js
function hideOrShow(executionContext){
  var a = executionContext.getFormContext().getAttribute("log_showhide").getValue();
  if (a == 0) {
    Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("SUMMARY_TAB").sections.get("sampleSection").setVisible(true);
  } else {
    Xrm.Page.ui.tabs.get("SUMMARY_TAB").sections.get("sampleSection").setVisible(false);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Rather than doing a custom web resource to show/hide a field or section, I would recommend you go with a Business Rule.  With a Business Rule you can set up a simple check of the value of one field and hide other fields based on that.

Comment: With simply condition like this question, Business Rule is more suitable than JS.

Comment: Except that BRs can't hide sections/tabs.  Only individual fields.

Answer (score 0):

Another way to hide a section by field's parent. Just refer a field on that section:

```
function SetProductVisible()
{
  var some_section = Xrm.Page.getControl("new_field_on_that_section_name").getParent();
  
  some_section.setVisible(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("ee_productspecific").getValue());
};
```